# React native / redux - setState cannot update during an existing state transition

Tags: javascript, express, react-native, react-redux, setstate

I'm developing an app using React Native and redux. Express js for the Ajax requests.

The data from my Ajax request won't load and here is the warning I'm getting:

> Warning: setState(...): Cannot update during an existing state
>   transition (such as within `render` or another component's
>   constructor). Render methods should be a pure function of props and
>   state; constructor side-effects are an anti-pattern, but can be moved
>   to `componentWillMount`.

Not entirely sure what I'm doing wrong?

index.ios.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

import {
  AppRegistry,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  NavigatorIOS
} from 'react-native'

import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
import store from './src/store'

import CategoryView from './src/category-view'

class myApp extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Provider store={store}>
        <NavigatorIOS
          initialRoute={{
            component: CategoryView,
            title: 'myApp',
            index: 0
          }}
        />
      </Provider>
    );
  }
}
```

store.js

```
import { combineReducers, createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux'
import thunkMiddleware from 'redux-thunk'
import category from './reducers/category'
import listings from './reducers/listings'

const reducers = combineReducers({
  category,
  listings
})

const initialState = {}

const store = createStore(
  reducers,
  initialState,
  applyMiddleware(
    thunkMiddleware
  )
)

export default store
```

Here is my view file:

```
import React from 'react'
import {
  View,
  ListView,
  ScrollView,
  StyleSheet,
  Image,
  TouchableHighlight
} from 'react-native'

import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import Listings from './listings'
import BetView from './bet-view'
import { getListings } from './actions/listings'

const getDataSource = (listings) =>
  (new ListView.DataSource({
    rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 != r2
  })).cloneWithRows(listings)

const _ListingsView = ({dataSource, navigator, onPress, onLoad}) => {
  onLoad()
  return(
    <ScrollView>
      <ListView
        dataSource={dataSource}
        renderRow={(row) =>
          <Listings
            teamOne={row.game[0]}
            teamTwo={row.game[1]}
            date={row.date}
            onPress={() => onPress(navigator, row.name)}
          />
        }
      />
    </ScrollView>
  )
}

const ListingsView = connect(
  (state) => {
    return {
      dataSource: getDataSource(state.listings.items || []),
      loading: state.listings.loading
    }
  },
  (dispatch) => {
    return {
      onPress: (navigator, name) =>
        navigator.push({
          title: 'test',
          component: BetView,
          passProps: {
            category: name
          }
        }),
      onLoad: () => dispatch(getListings())
    }
  }
)(_ListingsView)

export default ListingsView
```

Action file:

```
const URL = 'http://localhost:3000/listings'

export const REQUEST_LISTINGS = 'request-listings'
export const RECEIVE_LISTINGS = 'receive-listings'

const requestListings = () =>
({
  type: REQUEST_LISTINGS
})

const receiveListings = (items) =>
({
  type: RECEIVE_LISTINGS,
  items: items || []
})

const shouldFetch = (state) => {
  const res = (!state.listings.items || 0 == state.listings.items.length && !state.listings.loading)
  return res
}

export const getListings = () =>
  (dispatch, getState) =>
    shouldFetch(getState())
    && dispatch(requestListings())
    && fetch(URL)
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(json => dispatch(receiveListings(json)))
```

Here is the reducer:

```
import { RECEIVE_LISTINGS, REQUEST_LISTINGS } from '../actions/listings'

export default (state = {}, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case RECEIVE_LISTINGS:
      return {
        loading: false,
        items: action.items
      }
    case REQUEST_LISTINGS:
      return {
        loading: true,
        items: []
      }
  }
  return state
}
```

Comment: Are there any components in your app that use local state? In other words, are you calling `setState` anywhere?

Comment: This error usually happens when you try to update the state in the render function. React is declarative, so render should not manipulate the state.

Comment: Could be cause you are using a stateless component and everything happens during the render method. With a class base component you could wire the getDataSource inside componentWillMount

Comment: You are calling `onLoad()` in `render()` method of `_ListingsView`. Avoid this using component life cycle methods like `componentWillMount`

Comment: I've just updated with my question and added the index.ios.js showing the render method

Comment: the problem resides in _ListingsView. Every component has a render method but class based methods have more lifecycle methods, including componentWillMount.

Comment: Any chance you could show me an example on how you'd update _ListingsView

Comment: well I ll just give it an humble try then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could try something like this. I have not tested it. Not sure it is perfect. but that is the idea

```
import React, {Component} from 'react'
import {
  View,
  ListView,
  ScrollView,
  StyleSheet,
  Image,
  TouchableHighlight
} from 'react-native'

import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import Listings from './listings'
import BetView from './bet-view'
import { getListings } from './actions/listings'

const getDataSource = (listings) =>
  (new ListView.DataSource({
    rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 != r2
  })).cloneWithRows(listings)

class _ListingsView extends Component {


  componentWillMount() {
    this.props.onLoad();
  }

  render() {
    return(
      <ScrollView>
        <ListView
          dataSource={this.props.dataSource}
          renderRow={(row) =>
            <Listings
              teamOne={row.game[0]}
              teamTwo={row.game[1]}
              date={row.date}
              onPress={() => this.props.onPress(this.props.navigator, row.name)}
            />
          }
        />
      </ScrollView>
    )
  }
}

const ListingsView = connect(
  (state) => {
    return {
      dataSource: getDataSource(state.listings.items || []),
      loading: state.listings.loading
    }
  },
  (dispatch) => {
    return {
      onPress: (navigator, name) =>
        navigator.push({
          title: 'test',
          component: BetView,
          passProps: {
            category: name
          }
        }),
      onLoad: () => dispatch(getListings())
    }
  }
)(_ListingsView)

export default ListingsView
```

So you would be better following their example : https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/listview.html

Or this is how I manage ListViews in the application i am currently building: 
https://github.com/kamiranoff/mythology/blob/master/src/components/HeroesList/HeroesList.js 
(In that example it is a little different because the call to the api is made even before this component is render and on filtering the list, that is why I update the state of datasource in componentWillReceiveProps )

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'll give it a try and let you know.

Comment: Your solution did fix the setState warning but the data are still not loading. Might be something to do with this other issue it's complaining about:
Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 0):
React.Children.only expected to receive a single React element child.
Invariant Violation: React.Children.only expected to receive a single React element child.

Comment: can you point out from which component that error comes from in the full stacktrace ? Do you see any component you created ?

Comment: A react component has to return one single node (ex: <View />)

Comment: This error points to one of React Native library files, YellowBox.js (node_modules/react-native/Libraries/ReactNative/YellowBox.js)

Comment: <TouchableHighlight> was the source of the error. It must have only one child. Thanks a lot for your help.